# How to Add Dynamic Meta Tag to Site.Master from Database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

We have a series of meta tag values in our database that need to be passed to the Site.master depending on the site being served.  How would I include the BingMetaTag database field value in my Page Load event?  We need to pass the content attribute value from the database to the meta tag in the master page.

Page_Load is as follows:

```
 public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage {
    protected DealerInformation objDealerInformation = null;
    protected DealerSite objDealerSite = null;
    protected ConnectionStringConfig dbConfig = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        dbConfig = Session["DBConfig" + Request.Url.Host] as ConnectionStringConfig;
        objDealerInformation = CommonFunctions.GetDealerInformation(dbConfig);
        objDealerSite = Session["DealerSite" + Request.Url.Host] as DealerSite;

        try {
            imgGoogleAdServices.Src = string.Format(@"//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/{0}/?value=0&amp;label={1}&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0;", objDealerSite.GoogleConversionID, objDealerSite.GoogleConversionLabelRemarketing);
        } catch {
            imgGoogleAdServices.Src = "";
        }
        try {
            WebEntitiesModel context = new WebEntitiesModel(dbConfig["WebConnection"]);
            String aspPage = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString().ToLower();
            MetaTag pageMetaTag = (from m in context.MetaTags
                                   where m.Page == aspPage
                                   select m).Single();


            Page.Title = (pageMetaTag.PageTitle != null ? pageMetaTag.PageTitle : "");
            Page.MetaKeywords = (pageMetaTag.MetaKeywords != null ? pageMetaTag.MetaKeywords : "");
            Page.MetaDescription = (pageMetaTag.MetaDescription != null ? pageMetaTag.MetaDescription : "");
        } catch {
            Page.Title = "";
            Page.MetaKeywords = "";
            Page.MetaDescription = "";
        }
```

Note that we are already bringing in title, meta keywords and meta description from another database table.  We just need to add the value of BingMetaTag as a separate meta tag entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using WebForms rather than MVC, which actually makes this a bit easier.

In your Site.master file:

```
<head>
    <meta id="someMeta" runat="server" name="something" value="" />
</head>
```

In your Site.master.cs file's class:

```
protected HtmlGenericControl someMeta;

public String SomeMetaValue {
    get { return this.someMeta.Attributes["value"]; }
    set { this.someMeta.Attributes["value"] = value; }
}
```

In your page's class

```
public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

    SiteMaster master = (SiteMaster)this.Master;
    master.SomeMetaValue = "someValueFromDatabase";
}
```

If you have multiple types of Master pages in your project then this code will fail, so add appropriate guards and checks as needed.

Comment: +1 but it'd prob be easier to just do that in the master page itself so you only have to do it once.

Comment: In WebForms I think the MasterPage shouldn't have any logic of its own, the Page class should act as a controller.